# What is the fastest way to level 1-20?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Do you know how I can level up quickly to level 20?its hard for me to level and these quest barely give me xp I want to do dungeons but I'm low level (level 10)

Comment: is this your first time playing wow?

Comment: Yes but no,I played a year ago but i saw how good the game is now

Comment: just enjoy the game and do quests. YOUR experience grows with your characters experience :) why do you think you're slow anyways?

Comment: I just cant wait to get a kodo!

Comment: be clearer with your questiontitle on this site with your next questions.

Comment: This is not a duplicate - most of the advices given in suggested Q&A page are bad for levels 1-20 experience, because they take too long to setup, as you can level up to 20 lvl in one day... Since recently you get a cardback in Hearthstone for aquiring lvl 20 in WoW, so many people will come seeking for aid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest not trying to rush on anything. The content before end-game is super fun, so get involved in the game and enjoy the quests. Regardless, here are some tips on leveling faster:

- Have lots of bags so you don't have to go to vendors too often.
- Join a guild with a higher level than 6 so you can get the Fast Track perk which gives you 10 % exp boost. (**No longer valid as of the WoD expansion, guild levels no longer exist**)
- Once you can, queue up for dungeons every time you can when questing. Personally, it depends on your server and what spec you are. For example on a popular server as a tank, you probably will never quest if you constantly queue up, so only do it every two levels or so if you like dungeons. It's a different story for a dps spec. I was a troll warlock, and I waited about 10-20 minutes on a popular server for the queue.
- Battlegrounds are also a great way to gain exp, especially at low levels. You can easily gain a level or two if your team wins. Tank classes at this level are absurdly over-powered at this level, so if you have a tank spec it may be worth swapping over to it even temporarily for the rewards.

---

Source: Personal Experience.

Comment: He is level 10 though so he can't do dungeons yet (level 15). But he can queue up for battlegrounds, WSG and AB open up at level 10. Battlegrounds give tons of xp, especially when you win. They also do a great job showing you all the available classes and force you to think about which skills to use.

Comment: @Kevinw I added "Once you can" before but I must've misclicked something cause it didn't show. I added it now. Ahh thanks for the reminder of battlegrounds too.

Comment: I should point out that there is no such thing as 'Guild levels' anymore (unless I missed something)

Comment: Guys I'm level 17 now,how do I access dungeons?

Comment: @TarTar I recommend reading this article about the dungeon finder: http://www.wowwiki.com/Dungeon_Finder

Comment: Oh it's you again Chantal's we'll I'll look at this article then

Comment: Chantola* lol I messed up

Comment: There are no guild levels now.

Comment: What is there now?